# Format timestamp inside a set-column sentence

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-data-fusion

I'm developing a data fusion pipeline. It contains a wrangler node where I'm trying to create a new field that will contain the system date in timestamp format (yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH-mm-ss).

I've tried using the sentence:

```
set-column :sysdate (${logicalStartTime(yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH-mm-ss)})
```

But I receive the error:

```
Caused by: io.cdap.wrangler.api.DirectiveParseException: Error encountered while parsing 'set-column' : Error encountered while compiling '( 2022 -12-01T16-29-32 ) ' at line '1' and column '14'. Make sure a valid jexl transformation is provided.
```

Which would be the correct sentence?

I've tried:

```
set-column :sysdate (${logicalStartTime(yyyy-MM-ddHH-mm-ss)})
```

Which will result in something like "1877", as it substracts the numbers, and also tried:

```
set-column :sysdate (${logicalStartTime(yyyyMMddHHmmss)})
```

but the format isn't correct and can only be written if the field is a String.

Answer (score 0):

You have the correct method, just incorrect syntax. The syntax you are looking for is `set-column :sysdate ${logicalStartTime(yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH-mm-ss)}`, you have to remove `()`. Then you can convert the string in datetime pattern in this format `parse-as-datetime :sysdate "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH-mm-ss"`.

Answer (score 0):

If I were doing this, I'd set the target DB attribute to type DateTimeStamp (if it's supported) and use datetime-to-timestamp  'timezone'
then convert the datetimestamp on read to a DateTime format you like.

In the Wrangler window it would look like this

```
datetime-to-timestamp :DATE_CREATED
```

this casts from a DateTime to a Timestamp